# Excel VBA - How can I determine number of row label fields in Pivot Table?

Tags: excel, excel-2010, pivot-table, vba

I have an Excel 2010 pivot table containing, initially, 3 row label fields.

I need to create a macro that will add a certain field as the lowest row label field in the pivot table. (For reasons I won't go into, the user can't add this field in the normal way themselves.)

However, by the time the user runs this macro, they may have added or removed some row labels.

The macro recorder gives me this when I add a field in the lowest position of a pivot table (with 3 row labels already selected):

```
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("MyPivotTable").PivotFields("MyNewField")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 4
End With
```

If the user has added or removed some items, this position number 4 is incorrect. How would I pass into my code the correct position number?

Trying to aim high using `Position = 99` gives me the following error:

> Unable to set the Position property of the PivotField class

Any ideas please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`PivotFields` has a count property.

```
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("MyPivotTable").PivotFields("MyNewField")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("MyPivotTable").PivotFields.Count + 1
End With
```

Also, instead of `PivotFields`, you can substitute other selections to give you other counts:

- ColumnFields
- DataFields
- HiddenFields
- PageFields
- RowFields
- VisibleFields

Comment: `PivotFields.Count` gives you the total field count and not just the displayed count :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout, added info on other available counts

Comment: + 1 For suggesting an alternative method :)

Comment: Yes you are right. I was getting an error because of something else. I have rolled back the changes :)

Comment: I have also deleted my answer as your answer is better than mine :)

Comment: Thanks Gents - so to directly answer my question I would need to use `RowFields.Count`. Very useful, thanks very much!

Answer (score 2):

Try to throw away the `.Position = 4` string entirely, i.e.:

```
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("MyPivotTable").PivotFields("MyNewField")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
End With
```

Comment: Thanks Peter. This also works, and is very handy. However, because I also wanted to know how many row labels are currently used I've ticked Sean's answer.

Comment: @AndiMohr no problem, YOU choose the one you like the best) happy my option was somehow useful as well)

Answer (score 1):

A brute-force solution:

```
Public Function GetPivotFieldPos(pt As PivotTable, fieldName As String)
    Dim cnt As Integer
    Dim pos As Integer
    Dim pf As PivotField

    On Error GoTo ErrHandler

    cnt = 0   '  might be 1-based!?
    pos = -1
    For Each pf In pt.PivotFields
        cnt = cnt + 1
        If pf.Name = fieldName Then
            pos = cnt
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    GetPivotFieldPos = pos
    Exit Function

ErrHandler:
    GetPivotFieldPos = -1
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks, I was wondering if I'd have to go down this route, but Sean's answer is a neat solution.

Answer (score 1):

If the task at hand is to count the number of rowfields that may exist in a pivottable, you should enjoy this line of code:

```
pt.RowRange.cells.count
```

This will give the count of the pivotrows. However, this will count the heading row as well as the total row (if totals are applied to the pivottable.) So, you will need to subtract 1 or 2 depending on your situation.

[An excelent description of how to refer to pivottable ranges can be found here.](http://peltiertech.com/WordPress/referencing-pivot-table-ranges-in-vba/)

Comment: Thanks Timbur. Not quite what I was after but thanks for the useful link. Lots of handy hints there. Good old Jon Peltier :)